# Baofeng uv-82 will not transmit in channel mode?

Tags: transceiver

I have 2 Baofeng UV-82 radios. I programmed the frequencies using Chirp. When I try to access the repeaters in channel mode I cannot connect. When I switch to frequency mode and turn off the duplex offset, I can access the repeater. In channel mode I cannot talk to the other handheld. In frequency mode, I can talk to the other handheld. I made sure the T-CTCS frequency for the tone is set according to the repeater data. Any thoughts on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Hello Praetorian, and welcome to Amateur Radio SE and Stack Exchange. We work a little differently from a discussion forum that you may be used to; the goal here is to ask a specific question that has a specific answer. (You may or may not know what the answer is, or the answer might be "it can't be done", but a specific answers must exist to the question as asked.) Hence, all information needed to answer the question should be within the question itself.

Comment: Consequently, I suggest you [edit] your question to include all relevant information that might reasonably be needed to answer the question. A good start might be the programmed frequency, offset, tone and power settings, as well as input and output frequencies for the repeater you are trying to use. Also, include any other troubleshooting steps you have taken to confirm that your radios indeed actually *do not transmit* in channel mode but do transmit in frequency mode.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Looks like there's a multiple-account problem, so they may not be able to edit the question unless they were merged.

Comment: Like @KevinReidAG6YO points out, it looks like you might be using multiple accounts. **Please have a look at** [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and follow the instructions there, and you will be able to edit your question to provide more information. For the moment I am deleting what you posted as an answer because it is not an attempt at answering the question as asked. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have the offset (either direction or distance) configured incorrectly.  I would suggest you try to locate your state's repeater council's web site to see what the official frequency, tone, and off-set are.

Though there are standard offsets for repeaters on UHF and VHF, they can be configured by the trustee of the repeater, so if you can't connect then you might need to double check your info.

73 de N5JLC

Answer (score -1):

This just happened to me with a new UV-82HP purchased from Btech through Amazon. Btech support will send you a youtube link (https://youtu.be/CrG0El1KkIM) with a demonstration on how to program. Follow it exactly (assuming you have an HP).  When Btech became a problem, I took it to Amazon support linked in the Help side menu choice. I'd avoid CHirp for the time being. The FT-2900 issue (rendering radios inoperative) and my UV-82's blowup scare me.

Answer (score -2):

In short the unit is defective, despite rather called UV-82 or UV-82L the unit is defective. I have purchased and configured many Baofeng UV-82 units including the GT-3TP. of the 19+ UV-82 units I have programmed, I too have encountered that same problem a couple times. If you are using the chirp software and are copying and pasting the memory frequencies from a working unit in Channel mode, and still not able to transmit in channel mode then You know it's NOT a user programming error. I have successfully copied and pasted my fleet Memory Range before and after recognizing a brand new purchased defective units. again you have a defective unit, stop wrecking your brain re-programming that unit over and over thinking you missed a step, configured incorrectly or done something wrong. :-)

Comment: This is rarely the case.  In my experience many people consider the price of a new one easier to manage than the time needed to find a solution.  I have taken several "defective" UV-5Rs and a couple of UV-82s off of people's hands just to find they work just fine after resetting or reprogramming.  One person tried to unlock frequency limitations, which bricked it when he shorted solder in the wrong spot, but that's a rarity.  But this, of course, is just my experience.  YMMV